# Не получается наложить виджеты(надписи, поля ввода) на изображение

Tags: python, tkinter, изображения, виджет

Не получается наложить надписи на изображение, которое я установил на окно в виде фона.
Если убрать фон то надписи и поля ввода появляются. И так же фон без надписей отображается.

Ошибка:_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid

```
from tkinter import messagebox

root=Tk() #создаем окно
root.title('Авторизация')# Заголовок окна
root.geometry('900x700')# Размеры окна
root.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)# Если надо будет ограничить растяжение.
root['bg']='gold'# цвет окна внутри
root.image=PhotoImage(file="Book.png.png")
bg_logo=Label(root, image=root.image)
bg_logo.grid(row=0, column=0)



def registration():
    text=Label(text='Для входа в систему-зарегистритуйтесь!', font='Arial 30', bg='gold', fg='black')
    text.pack()
    text_firstname=Label(text='Введите ваше имя:', font='Arial 18', bg='gold', fg='black', padx=30)
    text_firstname.pack()
    register_lodin = Entry()
    register_lodin.pack()
    text_lastname=Label(text='Введите вашу фамилию:', font='Arial 18', bg='gold', fg='black', padx=30)
    text_lastname.pack()
    register_lodin = Entry()
    register_lodin.pack()
    text_patronymic = Label(text='Введите ваше отчество:', font='Arial 18', bg='gold', fg='black', padx=30)
    text_patronymic.pack()
    register_lodin = Entry()
    register_lodin.pack()
    text_log = Label(text='Введите логин ниже:', font='Arial 18', bg='gold', fg='black', padx=30)
    text_log.pack()
    register_log = Entry()
    register_log.pack()
    text_password = Label(text='Придумайте пароль:', font='Arial 18', bg='gold', fg='black', padx=30)
    text_password.pack()
    register_password = Entry()
    register_password.pack()
    text_repeatpassword = Label(text='Повторите пароль:', font='Arial 18', bg='gold', fg='black', padx=30)
    text_repeatpassword.pack()
    register_repeatpassword = Entry(show='*')
    register_repeatpassword.pack()





registration()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @insolor Спасибо! Заработало. Пожалуйста, оформите как ответ.

Comment: Оформил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В tkinter в одном и том же контейнере (например, в окне, фрейме) нельзя использовать одновременно `.grid()` и `.pack()`.

В данном случае для исправления ошибки можно просто размещать фон с помощью `.place()` по координатам 0, 0.